# Difference between Oracle and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle12c

I have a question about the difference between tablespace (Oracle) and database (SQL Server). I noticed that after you login to the SQL Server, you can directly create a database then a table.

However in Oracle, the database will be created during the installation then you can create a tablespace. So in this, is a tablespace in Oracle equivalent to table in SQL Server?

Also the command seems to be very different when creating a tablespace in Oracle and a table in SQL Server. Plus in Oracle when do you create the columns in the table?

In Oracle:

```
     Create Tablespace Car
     DATAFILE 'installed directory....'
     Autoextend on ........
     Extend Management Local
     Segment Space Management auto;
```

In SQL Server:

```
Create table Car 
(
    [column name 1] data type 1,
    ...................
    ...................
    ...................
    ...................
);
```

Comment: A tablespace is something completely different than a table. And you don't have to create a tablespace. A default `USERS` tablespace will be created during installation

Answer (score 2):

The mapping is like this:

```
Oracle      SQL Server
---------   -----------
Instance    Instance
Database    Database
Schema      Schema
Tablespace  Filegroup
```

Newer versions of Oracle support having multiple databases per instance, but traditionally Oracle had only a single database per instance.

This lead to a practice of using Schemas in Oracle for the purposes for which multiple Databases are typically used in SQL Server.

Comment: Your forgot that Oracle has a one-to-one mapping between schema and user